# На мобильном разрешении весь контента съезжает влево, исправить ошибку, html, css

Tags: html, css, frontend

https://maximys5582.github.io/buarning-man/

[image: Медиа запрос на изменение в зависимости от ширины экрана]
На мобильном разрешении 425px в ширину весь контейнер сдвигается влево, если убрать ширину 100% то всё "ок", кроме верхнего фото, оно находится в обрезанном формате

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ```.menu``` --> ```flex-wrap: wrap;```

Comment: Спасибо большое